# How do I approve pending records?

Tags: php, mysql, database, admin

I am working on a video-hosting website in which user-uploaded videos (called "answers" as they will be made in response to requests for help in hobby-making) are put into a pending list for a web administrator to examine and decide whether to approve for public viewing or not.

All video records have a boolean piece of data called "approved" that is set to either true ('1') or false ('0').

What I'm having trouble with is the actual approval process. No matter what I do, I can never get to set on the video's "approved" status.

Here is the code I have written...

**answer.php (Main video page)**

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" href="<?php echo url_for('/approve.php?id=' . h(u($answer['id']))); ?>"><i class="mr-2 fas fa-check fa-2x"></i>Approve</a>
```

**approve.php**

```
    if(!isset($_GET['id'])) {
      redirect_to(url_for('/pending.php'));
    }
    $id = $_GET['id'];


    if(is_post_request()) {

      $answer = [];
      $answer['id'] = $id;
      $answer['approved'] = $_POST['approved'];

      $result = approve_answer($id);
      $_SESSION['message'] = '<div class="text-success">The answer was successfully approved and ready for public viewing.</div>';  
      redirect_to(url_for('/pending.php'));

    } else {
      $answer = find_answer_by_id($id);
      $user = find_user_by_id($answer['user_id']);
    }

    ?>
    <?php $page_title = 'Confirm Approval'; ?>
    <?php include(SHARED_PATH . '/public_header.php'); ?>


    <div class="container my-2">
        <div class="my-2">
        <a class="back-link my-2" href="<?php echo url_for('/answer.php?id=' . h(u($answer['id']))); ?>"><i class="mr-2 fas fa-arrow-circle-left fa-2x"></i> Back to Answer</a>
        </div>

      <div class="answer approve">
        <h1>Confirm Approval</h1>
        <p>Are you sure you want to approve this answer?</p>
          <p class="item"><strong><?php echo h($answer['title']); ?></strong> by <emphasis><?php echo h($user['username']); ?></emphasis></p>
          <p><italics><?php echo h($answer['content']); ?></italics>

        <form action="<?php echo url_for('/approve.php?id=' . h(u($answer['id']))); ?>" method="post">
          <div id="operations">
            <input type="hidden" name="approved" value="1" />
            <input class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" name="approved" id="approved" value="Confirm" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div><!-- container -->
```

**function approve_answer (query_functions.php)**

```
function approve_answer($answer) {
    global $db;

    $errors = validate_answer($answer);
    if(!empty($errors)) {
      return $errors;
    }


    $sql = "UPDATE answers SET ";
    $sql .= "approved='" . db_escape($db, '1') . "', ";
    $sql .= "WHERE id='" . db_escape($db, $answer['id']) . "' ";
    $sql .= "LIMIT 1";

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    // For UPDATE statements, $result is true/false
    if($result) {
      return true;
    } else {
      // UPDATE failed
      echo mysqli_error($db);
      db_disconnect($db);
      exit;
    }

  }
```

So where have I gone wrong?

Comment: I don't believe you can specify LIMIT on an update query like that, if ID is a primary key you shouldn't need the limit.

Have you tried executing the query directly into your database to see any error?

Comment: No. I haven't, actually.

Comment: I'd recommend testing your query and testing it is getting to the function which executes the query `die($sql)`, I suspect LIMIT 1 is likely breaking this functionality.

Comment: You **can** specify `LIMIT` on an `UPDATE` clause. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: I stand corrected but still recommend testing the query. I also notice you have a comma before `WHERE`

Comment: Put some debugging in to ensure that you're getting the values throughout the process. As pointed out, there may be several places where this code is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Replace below code to query.

```
$sql = "UPDATE answers SET ";
$sql .= "approved='" . db_escape('1') . "', ";
$sql .= "WHERE id='" . db_escape($answer['id']) . "' ";
$sql .= "LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: What? `db_escape` is likely a custom function that was not specified here. Why did you removed the database handler variable (`$db`) from the argument list? How did you test this code? It very well may work, but you need to explain what the changes are and why the OP should make them.

Comment: Here I have seen to used db_escape function. What they do I don't know actual https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/db_escape/php-db_escape-function-examples.html

Comment: Those are just examples in open source code, not necessarily what OP's function is.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I have yet to apply your solution since I am at a loss at to why you removed the $db as well. You see, although it isn't specified in the code I shared with you, $db is a custom shorthand for db_connect();

Comment: Kamlesh, I just tried your solution just now and I'm sorry to say that it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
   if(!isset($_GET['id'])) {
      redirect_to(url_for('/pending.php'));
    }

    if(is_post_request()) {

      $result = approve_answer($_POST['id']);
      $_SESSION['message'] = '<div class="text-success">The answer was successfully approved and ready for public viewing.</div>';  
      redirect_to(url_for('/pending.php'));

    } else {
      $answer = find_answer_by_id($_GET['id']);
      $user = find_user_by_id($answer['user_id']);
    }

    ?>
    <?php $page_title = 'Confirm Approval'; ?>
    <?php include(SHARED_PATH . '/public_header.php'); ?>


    <div class="container my-2">
        <div class="my-2">
        <a class="back-link my-2" href="<?php echo url_for('/answer.php?id=' . h(u($answer['id']))); ?>"><i class="mr-2 fas fa-arrow-circle-left fa-2x"></i> Back to Answer</a>
        </div>

      <div class="answer approve">
        <h1>Confirm Approval</h1>
        <p>Are you sure you want to approve this answer?</p>
          <p class="item"><strong><?php echo h($answer['title']); ?></strong> by <emphasis><?php echo h($user['username']); ?></emphasis></p>
          <p><italics><?php echo h($answer['content']); ?></italics>

        <form action="<?php echo url_for('/approve.php?id=' . h(u($answer['id']))); ?>" method="post">
          <div id="operations">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" />
            <input class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" name="approved" id="approved" value="Confirm" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div><!-- container -->
```

### Query

```
    $sql = "UPDATE answers SET ";
    $sql .= "approved=1";
    $sql .= "WHERE id='" . db_escape($db, $answer) . "' ";
```

You can try this code. I am still not sure where you are setting the value for `$answer['user_id']` ? But this should solve your issue.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work either. And by the way, $answer['user_id'] represents the ID number video's author.

Comment: I see. Well you need to echo your query and check the final query is right or not? @BlackNoise